# Android api level requirement is minsdkversion 29 allowed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can someone clarify this for me. In the android manifest file I have

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="33"

Reading the google documentation https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

What is not clear to me is

*Starting in January 2023, app updates must target Android 12*

Am I correct in thinking that because I have "targetSdkVersion=33" I will be fine?

What role that minSDKVersion have in relation if is accepted by google?  Should minSDKVersion be 31 or I am allowed to put there 29?

Hope makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your app will be accpeted by the Goolge Play Store because your target sdk is heigher than Api 31. And then about the minSDKVersion, the official document's explain:

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

Google doesn't have a request for this attribute. And the android official document said:

> If you do not declare this attribute, the system assumes a default value of "1", which indicates that your application is compatible with all versions of Android.

So if your application is compatible with the lower versions, such as it can run well on the Android 10 or lower, you can set it as 29.

For more information, you can check the [official document about the uses-sdk attributes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element).

Comment: thanks for your details answer too.. makes all sense now

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll be fine with your `targetSdkVersion`:

> New apps must target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher

The `minSdkVersion` is unaffected by this. This property defines how many older versions you want to support in your app. Your potential user base is much higher if you target older versions as well, but you'll may have to spend additional effort on maintaining backward compatibility.

A rough estimate of the **cumulative usage** of the API levels across all devices can be seen on [apilevels.com](https://apilevels.com/). With `minSdkVersion=29`, your app supports about 77.7% of all Android devices:

[image]

*Cumulative usage distribution figures in this screenshot are of February 7, 2023*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer my main worry is/was the role minsdkversion plays in terms of google accepting the app. So when it comes to nov 2023 my app will still be available for download because of it regardless of the minsdkversion

Comment: I wish I could split the acceptance..